# Why I'm not able to display the label text properly in tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

[Here is the image for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EobxL.png) here I had used a separate view [as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHsCl.png) on the table view cell and I have text that may increase or decrease more than two lines but when I used this code it was setting as expected but it is  not having same height of all cells and in storyboard I had set the label properties like `lines = 0` and `line break = word wrap`

```
        tableDetails.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

When I get only one word in the table view after running the application it was setting in the label perfectly but when I scroll down and up the table view text was arranging as shown in the image

Comment: pls add image of your prototype-cell.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l57BQ.png here is the image for my proto type cell

Comment: Did you set autolayout constraint for the upper label ??

Comment: @thiru What is the constraints you have give to upper label?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qtO.png these are the constarints for my name label

Comment: @gEeKyMiNd i had set autolayout constraints for name label also

Answer (score 4):

If your are using autolayout then do the following steps in you uitableview cell view:

1- For the label which you want to be dynamic according to the text add contraints from all 4 side without adding any height and width contraints.

2- Make number of lines 0 for the label

3-If you are having labels below the label which you want to expand dynamically add contraints from left right and bottom. Don't add contraints from top.

4- In your view controller where you have added the tableview add the following Code:

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 )
{
    tbl.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tbl.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;
}
```

Comment: already i had used this code it was working but where  as coming to one word then the label text was not displaying properly when i scroll down or up after running application check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EobxL.png

Comment: @thiru have you done the steps of autolayout which i have mentioned??

Comment: As i can see in your given image you are using an imageView , a label , a text field and buttons for plus and minus. Right??

Comment: yes if i set no. of lines = 0 then the label was displaying text properly but when i get the text as shown in the image then the text was changing as said previously

Comment: Follow the steps: Remove all autolayouts from the cell. Firsly Add contraints to UIimageView bt adding left and top contraint and height &  width also. Then for the label add from all four side and no of line=0, make sure that the label bottom contrain is from uitextfield. Then add contraint to textfield by adding from left, right and bottom . then add copontrain to Plus minus button according to your convience.

Comment: and dont forget to add the the code given above and dont use heightforrowatindexpath delegate for tableview.

Comment: i forget to say i have placed an another view on the uitableview cell is it the problem causing ?

Comment: @thiru no that is not the problem ...autolayout of that view will be as follow: Add constraint from all four side without height and widht

Answer (score 1):

You have given Wrong Constraints to your label :
 Try giving Constraints as [leading with your image and top from view]
 It works for me.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uXAD.png

Comment: i had given the constraints what u have said check this for my name label https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qtO.png

Answer (score 0):

It's totally dependent on the frame of the label. There may be the following reasons:
1. Check once again for the line break mode of the label it seems characterWrap according to your image.
2. Try to debug with the frame print the frame of label for each label and check for width, is it right that you want?

OR 
Cross check your constraints too.

Comment: i have given character wrap also but the problem continues same may be problem with the given constraints or what  ?

Comment: what's the constraint you have on label?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qtO.png here are the constraints i had given for name label

Comment: @thiru set background color of label & run it.you can easily identify the problem is frame or alignment or constraints

Comment: @DSDharma https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlWn4.png here is the image for that i didn't figure out what the problem was

Comment: @DSDharma when ever i scroll up and down the width of the name label was reducing that's the only thing i observed how to avoid that any suggestions ?

Comment: i m not sure exactly seems constraints was not setted properly.clear the constraints & do it again.this time give width & height constantly.Make center horizontal of item count(1) & vertical spacing to

Comment: if i give height constant then the name label won't increase if the no. of lines increases now what should i do in this case  ?